# Beamer: image next to text with a caption

Tags: beamer, graphics

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
       \begin{columns}
          \column{0.38\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{example-image}
             \captionof[graphics]{test}
           \column{0.58\linewidth}
              \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
                wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
                14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
                 waar hij een school stichtte.
         \end{columns} 
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to add a short caption to the image, how may I do this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `\captionof` macro you

- have to load the caption package
- the correct syntax is `\captionof{figure}{your caption text}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.38\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{example-image}
      \captionof{figure}{test}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.58\linewidth}
      \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
      wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
      14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
      waar hij een school stichtte.
    \end{column}
  \end{columns} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or you could place your image in a `figure` environment and use the normal `\caption{...}` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\def\leq{\leqslant} % eleganter \leq-symbool
\def\geq{\geqslant} % eleganter \geq-symbool

\title{De regel van Horner: \\ Een vleugje geschiedenis}
\date{}
\subject{Slides voor het vak Vakdidactiek wiskunde} % zichtbaar in het "Properties"   venster van de PDF-viewer
\keywords{LaTeX, beamer, presentaties} % idem

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.38\linewidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=3.5cm]{example-image}
        \caption{test}
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.58\linewidth}
      \textbf{William George Horner} (geboren in 1786, gestorven in 1837) was een Brits
      wiskundige. Hij studeerde aan de Kingswood School in Bristol, waar hij reeds op
      14(!)-jarige leeftijd een masteropleiding volgde. Daarna trok hij richting Bath
      waar hij een school stichtte.
    \end{column}
  \end{columns} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```